# How to use a void variable created in differnt package?

Tags: java, eclipse

[Package and class hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXrWK.png)

Hello, I am new to programming and would love to get some help. I am try to make a simple program in eclipse to work out few basic equations. I have made 2 packages, 
"Equations", and "Workspace".

This is the class "quadraticEquation" in equations package.

```
package Equations;
import java.util.*;

public class quadraticEquation {

    //ax^2 + bx + c = 0

    double a,b,c;
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    void calculateQuadEq() {
        System.out.println("Enter a");
        a = input.nextDouble(); 
        System.out.println("Enter b");
        b = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter c");
        c = input.nextDouble();

        double z = Math.pow(b, 2) - (4*a*c);
        if(z<0) {
            System.out.println("This equation has no real roots");
        } else if(z==0) {
            double m = -b/(2*a);
            System.out.println("There are 2 equal roots to this equation, " + m + " and " + m);
        } else if(z>0) {
            double m = (-b + (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c))/2*a;
            double n = (-b - (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 *a*c))/2*a;

            System.out.println("There are 2 real roots to this equation, " + m + " and " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

I am successfully able to run the variable `calculateQuadEq` in the same package (have tried) but when it comes to a different package, I am not able to. I tired importing the class file like this.

[Variable not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unOCQ.png)

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: `calculateQuadEq`  is a method. It is not a variable.

Comment: It's not available because the variable is package-private. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html Use a modifier like public.

Comment: your method is package protected, use public void calculateQuadEq

Comment: Also use Java naming conventions. Classes (and other types like interfaces, enum) should start with uppercase. This helps us to distinguish `fields` and `methods(..)` from `Types` and constructors like `Type(..)` while reading the code.

Comment: Thanks guys! Making it public worked for me. Also sorry for the repeat question :(